# Traffic redirector using Python, socket() and maybe proxy type functionality

Tags: python, sockets, routes

I would like to use Python to redirect (ie **route**) internet bound traffic via a specific interface based on some logic (eg based on source IP address). The traffic can be anything (not just http(s) traffic).

The server that I would like the Python program to run can be the default gateway. ie Some internet traffic will be redirected towards this Python server. I will enable promiscuous mode on the interface. I am looking to capture this traffic using potentially python sockets for servers.

I do not want to change any IP addresses. So it does not seem to me that it is a pure client/server model, where I am in control of the destinations nodes.

My challenge here is using the socket() (regardless of Python, C++ ...) which seems to be designed for client-server models.

How can I simply "route" traffic through like this using Python?

Any suggestions would be great, including about my approach of using sockets. Maybe my approach is wrong, and should incorporate open-source proxy servers instead of Python's socket() functionality.[See diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqsBk.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a dup, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51382936/238704) and its answers and comments seems to have enough information to get you further along. You might also find [scapy](https://scapy.net/) to be a useful toolbox for this.

Comment: Thanks James for the suggested link, I will need it down the line once I sort out the routing piece first. On the other hand, I find scapy as a tool only for traffic generation, and could see a way to see inside their library of function what they provide. I like their product though, it was interesting. Thanks again.

Comment: scapy is **not** a tool limited to traffic generation. Look at the second example under the "More Examples" heading on [this page](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html). The `sniff()` method is pretty nice.