# A receiver that can receive both TCP images and UDP texts

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to socket programming . I've implemented 2 separated codes on the same host. One of them is supposed to receive images using TCP protocol and the second one is supposed to receive text messages through UDP protocol. Both of them are working fine separately. Here are the codes:

**Image receiver (TCP):**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
from struct import unpack
import Queue
from PIL import Image


HOST = '10.0.0.1'
PORT = 12345
BUFSIZE = 4096
q = Queue.Queue()

class Receiver:
    ''' Buffer binary data from socket conn '''
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.buff = bytearray()

    def get(self, size):
        ''' Get size bytes from the buffer, reading
            from conn when necessary 
        '''
        while len(self.buff) < size:
            data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            self.buff.extend(data)
        # Extract the desired bytes
        result = self.buff[:size]
        # and remove them from the buffer
        del self.buff[:size]
        return bytes(result)

    def save(self, fname):
        ''' Save the remaining bytes to file fname '''
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            if self.buff:
                f.write(bytes(self.buff))
            while True:
                data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)

def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind failed', err)
        return
    sock.listen(1)
    print('Socket now listening at', HOST, PORT)
    try:
        while True:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Connected with', *addr)
            # Create a buffer for this connection
            receiver = Receiver(conn)
            # Get the length of the file name
            name_size = unpack('B', receiver.get(1))[0] 
            # Get the file name itself
            name = receiver.get(name_size).decode()
            q.put(name)
            print('name', name)
            # Save the file
            receiver.save(name)
            conn.close()
            print('saved\n')

    # Hit Break / Ctrl-C to exit
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')

    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Text receiver (UDP):**

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "10.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

Now my question is: How can I merge these 2 codes? I don't want to open 2 separate consoles for each of them and I want one code instead of two. Is it possible?

---

I tried the solution which was provided in the comment and here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from select import select
import socket
from struct import unpack

host = '10.0.0.2'
port = 5005
size = 8000
backlog = 5

class Receiver:
    ''' Buffer binary data from socket conn '''
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.buff = bytearray()

    def get(self, size):
        ''' Get size bytes from the buffer, reading
            from conn when necessary 
        '''
        while len(self.buff) < size:
            data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            self.buff.extend(data)
        # Extract the desired bytes
        result = self.buff[:size]
        # and remove them from the buffer
        del self.buff[:size]
        return bytes(result)

    def save(self, fname):
        ''' Save the remaining bytes to file fname '''
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            if self.buff:
                f.write(bytes(self.buff))
            while True:
                data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)


def read_tcp(s):
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected with', *addr)
    # Create a buffer for this connection
    receiver = Receiver(conn)
    # Get the length of the file name
    name_size = unpack('B', receiver.get(1))[0]
    name = receiver.get(name_size).decode()
    print('name', name)
    # Save the file
    receiver.save(name)
    conn.close()
    print('saved\n')

def read_udp(s):
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(8000)
    print("Recv UDP:'%s'" % data)

def run():

    # create tcp socket
    tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcp.bind((host,port))
    tcp.listen(1)

    # create udp socket
    udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    udp.bind((host,port))

    input = [tcp,udp]

    while True:
        inputready,outputready,exceptready = select(input,[],[])

        for s in inputready:
            if s == tcp:
                read_tcp(s)
            elif s == udp:
                read_udp(s)
            else:
                print("unknown socket:", s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

but I don't receive any UDP or TCP packet now and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Check this: [use select() to listen on both tcp and udp message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160980/use-select-to-listen-on-both-tcp-and-udp-message)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use select() to listen on both tcp and udp message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160980/use-select-to-listen-on-both-tcp-and-udp-message)

Comment: @sal It didn't help me much since I'm receiving two different formats (one is text and the other one is image). I have multiple *def*s in my TCP receiver which makes it a little difficult and confusing for me to organize the code as it is suggested in this link.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer yes, but you will need to implement multithreading for this. For instance, your program will spawn two threads, one for TCP sockets and other for UDP.

Comment: While this problem can be solved using multithreading, multithreading is not required (or even necessarily recommended).  You can also accomplish the same functionality using a single thread and an I/O multiplexing function like `select()` or `poll()`.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I wasn't aware of that, thanks! I will need to read more about thoose functions.